# How do you remove a web proxy from your config?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

While looking for a solution to a problem, I added an `InternetWebProxy` to our Exchange server configuration:

```
Set-ExchangeServer -Identity SBS -InternetWebProxy foo
```

Now my proxy is set to `foo`, but how do I undo that change again?

I tried setting it to `""`, `''`, ``` `` ```, `Null`, `False`, but nothing is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$null`:

```
Set-ExchangeServer -Identity SBS -InternetWebProxy $null
```